# How can I disable actions that cause my CD tray to open?

Tags: windows-10

For example, when using the file browser to save a file, if I accidentally click on the CD tray icon, it will tell me there's no disc inserted and then open it. I would very much prefer the icon to disappear altogether if no disc is inserted, but if that's not possible then at least keep it from deciding I want to insert something then and there.